# How to do front-end formatting of HTML tags in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, frontend

Im working with webservices and javascript... My javascript app pulls down information from the webserivce, but the problem is that some of the information still has the HTML tags in it, for example: `&apos;` and `&amp;` for an apostrophe and ampersand, respectively.

Is there any javascript library, or even third party library, that does the formatting of the HTML tags? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to format it?

Comment: Those are not tags, they are entities. Tags have angle brackets.

Comment: I apologize, I meant entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this trick

```
yourtext = $('<div/>').html(yourText).text();
```